# How do I express a dependency in Gradle for two projects at the same directory level?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, dependencies, project

EDIT: I have the main project compiling. However, the test project starts to compile and then bombs saying it cannot find packages from the main project wherever it encounters an import statement.

This is directory structure:

```
Root Folder A (contains no project)
    settings.gradle

Main Program Folder B (contains Android application project)
    build.gradle

Testing Program Folder C (contains junit test project that references the Main Program)
    build.gradle
```

I have a settings.gradle file in Parent Folder that looks like this:
    include 'B', 'C'

Folder B has its own build.gradle file, nothing special.

Folder C has its own build.gradle file that looks like the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
    }       

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
        compile project (':B')
    }
```

I open a cmd prompt at the root and type `gradle build`.

Comment: Try lowercase: `gradle build`

Comment: Thanks, but I just uppercased it here for emphasis.

Comment: Ok, I emphasized it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Build files should be called `build.gradle`, not `gradle.build`.

`settings.gradle` should `include 'B', 'C'`

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html for a good example

Comment: That was my dyslexia kicking in. ;) I changed the settings as you suggested, but I am still getting same errors. Any reference to main project is flagged as symbol not found.

Comment: I also notice that it is trying to compile **three** projects instead of two. One line says 'Evaluating root project using empty build file.'

Comment: Edited my question. I am closer but the second project will not compile. Is there no one out there who can help me solve this simple problem??

Comment: It could probably be helpful to show the "nothing special" build files. Or provide a link to your actual code.

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/xedious/gradle-build.git  I put all the commands into one build.gradle on the root directory to make it easier to read.

Comment: I'll have a little look. First tip: Learn about `.gitignore` and what should be in source control and not.

Comment: Thanks. I know, I was in a hurry.  My manager saw it and said that he would berate me for doing that.

Comment: I tried a bit, but had problems as well. I suppose a few tips may be: Start as simple as possible. Try to create a project in Android Studio, and add modules in it. That could give you some good pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to create one project in Android Studio and let it build the Gradle files.

Directory structure:

```
A
|
settings.gradle
build.gradle
app
  |
  build.gradle
  src
    |
    B
    C
```

Root settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
```

Root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.b"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.1.0-beta"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("./debug.keystore")
        }

        if (System.getenv("KEYSTORE") != null && System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD") != null) {
            release {
                println "Release signing key detected"
                storeFile file(System.getenv("KEYSTORE"))
                storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
                keyAlias "B"
                keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (System.getenv("KEYSTORE") != null) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.1"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1"
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
}
```